# Unable to Preview Excel file Attachment in Microsoft Office 365

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, office365

I installed Office 365, when I open an email on Outlook I can't preview the file attached if it is an excel document. 
It shows the message

> "This file cannot be previewed because there is no previewer installed for it"

Thus when I click it twice it doesn't open even though I already have all updates installed and I also checked the registry as a recommendation from Microsoft.

Comment: Are you using the Desktop Outlook app? Do you have Excel installed on the local computer?

Comment: If you save the attachment locally, what is the file extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the desktop Office application, you may first try to run a repair of your Office installation and then test it again. For your convenience: [Repair Office installation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b).

I noted you have checked the registry as a recommendation from Microsoft. Not sure whether you have checked the correct registry key, you may follow the following Microsoft KB article to double check it:

["This file cannot be previewed because there is no previewer installed for it" error when you preview Excel workbooks in Outlook 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3100511/this-file-cannot-be-previewed-because-there-is-no-previewer-installed)